# Mongodb database schema diagram

Tags: mongodb

How can I create a  Mongodb database schema diagram?
I   read the documentation in mongodb.org,  but it is was not clear for me. Maybe  Someone can help me with this, i have a db with embebed documents.

Comment: MongoDB is a schemaless database. How do you expect to create a diagram for something which doesn't exist?

Comment: something basic, just representing the collections and the references or the collections and if exist the embebed documents with a generally example.i just asked because  maybe exists a standar or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While MongoDB is a schemaless database there are a couple generators out there which do a nice job of creating a json schema representation. I find it particularly useful when looking for strategies for sharding or migrating. The output is very nice and the code is easily readable. I've personally adapted it to generate HTML tables and PDFs.

https://github.com/variety/variety

Comment: This answer is now almost 8 years old. Have there been any better tools or approaches since then?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a flexible schema. Therefore, you can not list all fields unless fetching all documents in a collection. An alternative is defining schema in some kind of data structure(struct, associative array, class or other user defined structrue) or config file and then print it in diagram format.